# gdURL permalinks no longer working

Tags: google-drive, links, google-drive-sharing, url-shortening

gdURL.com provides a free service where one can create direct permalinks for google drive files. I have used it for a few years now, and haven't had any issues.

Now, whenever I (or a third party) try to access them, this error appears:

```
 "Error: The requested file/URL has been deleted from Google Drive and/or gdURL."
```

I have not deleted, moved or altered these files that have previously worked. I have gone back to gdURL and tried to create new permalinks for these files, but it says that the original files already exist, and they show the number of downloads, etc. for them.

If you look at the gdURL.com FAQ, they have this information under "Do you offer any guarantees?":

> after 8 years of providing this service, in January 2020 Google
> started blocking the manner in which we determined if files still
> existed, causing us to mark countless files as "deleted in Google
> Drive." As a result, we are no longer able to determine if files are
> deleted or have become private in Google Drive, so links to any such
> files will just land visitors at some kind of Google error page
> henceforth

Yet *some* of my files still work (the most recent ones), and others do not. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: As this is the first question about gdURL and there isn't a tag yet for this "web app" it might be a good idea that you provide more details about it and if you already tried to contact the gdURL support / developers.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, I have added a bit more detail. There appears to be no way to contact any support/devs on the website. Please let me know if this is not an appropriate Q for Web Applications, and I can try to find a better SE site for it.

Comment: Thanks. Ignoring "Or is gdURL just becoming less useful?" or considering it a rhetorical question I think that the post is fine here.